# How to properly extract JSON response in curl PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this code in `php` that retrieves login authentication from an API. My problem is, I cannot properly extract the curl response from this code.

```
$baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";
$loginURL = $baseURL."/login";

$data = array(
        'email'=>'sample@email.com',
        'password'=>'sample'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$preAuthToken = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Response: ".$preAuthToken;
```

What it displays in page is something like tjis

```
 {
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU0NDE3ODU3NSwiZXhwIjoxNTQ0MTgyMTc1LCJuYmYiOjE1NDQxNzg1NzUsImp0aSI6IjRSVEhiNGx3aUxoYTlJZjciLCJzdWIiOjUsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEiLCJtZXJjaGFudENvZGUiOiI4NTYyMzJiYSIsImhhc2hlZElkIjoiOHYiLCJsb2dpblR5cGUiOiJtZXJjaGFudFVwbG9hZCIsIjJmYUVuYWJsZWQiOmZhbHNlfQ.gnpmb8HbeRK7FlG5b-GDh-CMR5oBA5qXWfjcEtZZTs8",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":3600
 }Response: 1
```

I am confused why the echoed response is `Response: 1`?
How can I properly extract the `JSON` response and get the `access_token` field?

Comment: Since you're not using _RETURNTRANSFER, the response goes straight to stdout. And the trailing garbage is caused by `echo "Response: ".$preAuthToken;`

Comment: You can use this tools to convert cURL command into PHP. https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: oh ok. I got it thanks.